# no source available to run tests in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core

I'm having trouble debugging a project. When I double click on the tests to open them, it says "no source available" and I can not also debug or run a specific one. I can only run them all by the tool or by git bash using dotnet test.

Any idea what that might be? These problems started when we migrated to ASP.NET Core.

Project is with net461.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you rebuilt the test assemblies?

Comment: if rebuilding does not help try deleting the hidden folder .vs in the solutions folder.  You will have to close visual studio to do it.

Comment: Yes, I made this so many times.

Comment: @KenTucker I made this and it's still not working :(

Comment: @nelsontruran yes

Comment: You will have to add screen shots or more detailed steps. This question right now won't help others understand what exactly you hit.

Comment: @LexLi I'll update the question with this in a few minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Restarting visual studio and building test assembly did it for me.